# How to repeat a word based on the given number?

Tags: javascript, string

Example, we have this string `1 jar 2 melon 5 ice` it will turn into `jar melon melon ice ice ice ice ice`. Another example, `2 dress 1 mouse 3 jar 1 phone` > `dress dress mouse jar jar jar phone`. How can I do that in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Done with JS `RexExp`:

```js
let str = "1 jar 2 beers 3 melons"
let res = str.replace(/([1-9]\d*)\s(\w+)/g, (substring, arg1, arg2)=>{
  return (arg2+" ").repeat(parseInt(arg1)).slice(0, -1); // replaces substring with arg2 repeated `parseInt(arg1)` times
}); // jar beers beers melons melons melons

console.log(res)
```

Comment: `[1-9]\d*` is equal to `\d+` and since you are using arrow function, you can drop `return` by removing curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you are innocently desiring to learn coding and not trying to do some random shortcut:*

**Step 1:** We could use regex to split the string and mess with it from there:

```js
const str = "1 jar 2 melon 5 ice";
let arr = str.split(/ (?=\d)/g); // match spaces that are proceeded by a number
// ["1 jar", "2 melon", "5 ice"]
```

**Step 2:** Extract the numbers by splitting again:

```js
arr = arr.map(i => {
  i = i.split(" ");
  const num = +i[0]; // cast string to number
  const word = i.slice(1).join(" "); // join rest of the string
  return (word + " ").repeat(num).trim();
});
```

**Step 3:** Build the result:

```js
const result = arr.join(" ");
```

At the end, your code would look like:

```js
const str = "1 jar 2 melon 5 ice";
let arr = str.split(/ (?=\d)/g);
arr = arr.map(i => {
  i = i.split(" ");
  const num = +i[0];
  const word = i.slice(1).join(" ");
  return (word + " ").repeat(num).trim();
});

const result = arr.join(" ");

console.log(result);
```